# Mass regex group replace

Tags: html, css, regex

I am a complete noob with this whole regexr thing and I am no programmer but willing to learn new things.  Is it possible to add replace with custom regex in regexr or notepad++ regex?

I mean, if you look into the sample below, the results recognise the replacement regex expression as string characters. Case in point here : http://regexr.com/3db5p

For instance, how can I find

```
([.])[ ]{1,}([A-Z])\w+\s\s([a-z])\w+
```

and change it to

```
([.])[ ]{1,}{[A-Z]}\w+\s\s\s([a-z])\w+
```

all the while maintaining the characters and all from this :

input sample : http://regexr.com/3db65

to this :

output sample : http://regexr.com/3db68

(So I just wanted to add one whitespace without affecting the rest)

because I have a lot of text satisfying this particular pattern and I only want to change those without affecting the rest.

**Edit**: I have another extra sample here, with the whole length of text (and have even more of that patterns in 20 other files: http://regexr.com/3db5p (284 matches).

I have multiple instances whereby I need to change only precisely those patterns without messing with other parts with double whitespaces (which are all over the place).

That is the reason why finding expression only containing two or more whitespace and replace it wont fulfill the task I am doing.

Thank you for all the quick replies! Much appreciated! Feel free to give me any kinds of creative and inventive suggestion! (like using other editor or programming language) They are all very much welcome!

Comment: Just replace \s\s+ by \s.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gU6tQ5/1

Comment: @pagkly you may [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

 So in regexr, apparently, I need to change the find to this (making a group):

**([.])[ ]{1,}([A-Z]\w+)[ ]{2,}([a-z]\w+)** 

and in replace:

**$1 $2   $3**

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the contribution! Much appreciated! I am doing this to transfer pdf texts to anki flashcard and for note taking purposes (there are a lot of repeating errors on adobe acrobat OCR part hence why it has to be in custom pattern). If I were to do this repeating, industrious task of identifying and replacing them one by one, it would take hours, days of work, few weekend nights; which can be utilised for extra revision, gym, or hanging out. So, the bottom line is regex is the way to go! Find the pattern, press enter and done!

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace `/ {2,}/` with a white space  see <kbd>[demo](http://regexr.com/3db5s)</kbd>

Comment: Why not simply `/ +/`? Also what's that capturing group?

Comment: @Shafizadeh you're right about the capturing group, I'll remove it. I prefer the `{2,}` because it avoid replacing space by... a space :)

Comment: @Thomas but the whole sample will be changed! If that happens, all 1235 instances and not 284 will be replaced

Comment: @pagkly did you try?

Comment: @Thomas I did try with the previous sample but it was not the one I am looking for when I apply it to the whole text. But thanks for the time and effort! Yeah I do realize my method is too overcomplicated but for the most part I get the job done without further editing.

Answer (score 0):

the regex you need to replace **two** or more **white spaces** with only **one** is:

```
\s{2,}
```

http://regexr.com/3db5v

---

**PHP example**:

```
<?php
$text = "Budgeting  After studying this chapter";
echo preg_replace('/\s{2,}/i', ' ', $text);
//Budgeting After studying this chapter
```

Comment: but it will change the rest of the file which I do not want to mess with  (it becomes 1235 matches)

Comment: Please post a clear ***INPUT*** and desired ***OUTPUT*** sample

Comment: Thank you for your time @Pedro! There are a lot of changes to be made so... I guess I will try to make the output by changing the input text one by one... or maybe try with a shorter sample with the output?

Comment: The input and output is on the post now. This time, I decided to add one extra whitespace (\s\s\s) on the output instead of erasing one to become (\s) before.